# WPF datagrid Binding error?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working on networking based application the application connects with a networking device using C# the front end is on WPF .The problem is i want to extract data after running particular command and after extraction i want it to display on DataGrid.The data is extracting correctly using regex as i need but the part that i want to show on Datagrid is not showing however it is showing on console correctly .Code is:

```
public class IPMAC
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string mac { get; set; }
}

List<IPMAC> ipmac = new List<IPMAC>();
string pattern = @"(F8-F7-D3-00\S+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
    ipmac.Add(new IPMAC(){mac=match.Groups[1].Value});
}
string pattern2 = @"(192.168.1\S+)";
MatchCollection matchesIP = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern2);

foreach (Match match in matchesIP)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
    ipmac.Add(new IPMAC() { ip = match.Groups[1].Value });
```

XAML is :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="dg" Grid.Row="0" Height="250" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >     
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mac Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=mac}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=ip}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In short I don't understand how to show output on datagrid as it is showing on Console .Please help??

Comment: how about `dg.ItemsSource = ipmac;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to display your list of `IPMAC` in `DataGrid` is, by setting `ItemsSource` from code after the list has been populated :

```
dg.ItemsSource = ipmac;
```

or you can use `DataBinding` by following below steps :

- **set up `DataContext` properly**. Because data binding resolves binding path from current data context.
- **declare `ipmac` as public property of type `ObservableCollection`**. `ObservableCollection` has built in mechanism to notify UI to refresh whenever item added to or removed from collection. And data binding can't work with member/field.
- **bind `ItemsSource` to `ipmac` property**.

Snippet demonstrating above steps :

```
//declare ipmac as public property
public ObservableCollection<IPMAC> ipmac { get; set; } 

//In constructor : initialize ipmac and set up DataContext
ipmac = new ObservableCollection<IPMAC>();
this.DataContext = this;

//In XAML : bind ItemsSource to ipmac
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding ipmac}" Name="dg" ... />
```

Comment: It solved my problem feeling great now but one more thing it is showing mac address on one row and ip on 2nd row what would be the issue?

Comment: That's strange. No idea without more information. Are you sure it isn't the collection that was populated with wrong data?